# triger jquery tag manager after 3 characters typed

Tags: jquery, tags

I have used j-Query Tags Managers and Its working fine. but Now I need to trigger tags search after 3 chars typed in  the text box. as of Its starts searching as soon as I type a first char.

Here is my code.

```
var tagApi = $(".tm-input").tagsManager({
                delimiters: [44]});
jQuery(".typeahead").typeahead({
                    name: 'tags',
                    displayKey: 'name',
                    source: function (query, process) {
                            return $.get(<URL for Ajax Request>, { query: query }, function (data) {
                            data = $.parseJSON(data);
                            return process(data);
                            });
                    },
                    afterSelect :function (item){
                                  tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", item);
                                }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you can use `minLength` param of typeahead plugin:

```
jQuery(".typeahead").typeahead({
   name: 'tags',
   displayKey: 'name',
   minLength: 3, // Can you try by adding this line of code
....
});
```

[**minLength**](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/)

> Search by **default** value 2 (characters)
>
> The number of characters typed inside the search input before
>   searching for results. It is possible to set this option to 0 and
>   combine it with `searchOnFocus: true` to display a set of results by
>   default.